# My data.json have a link and i want to access that link in my view how to access that without using innerhtml in angular

Tags: angular

Below is my json file data.json:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "POC",
        "desc": "<a href='www.google.com'>HOMEPAGE</a>",
        "status": "done",
        "percentage_finished": 100
    }
```

and i want to get this link on my view page how to get that without using innerHtml.

Comment: "desc": "<a href='www.google.com'>HOMEPAGE</a>" this is the link how to read this link in my angular app without using innerhtml

Answer (score 0):

If you assign this Object to a variable (let's pretend is called `data`). Then you can simply do:

```
this.data.desc = this.data.desc.split(/\'(.*?)\'/)[1]
```

This will take the string `<a href='www.google.com'>HOMEPAGE</a>` and it will split it by the `' '` characters. the result is an array like this:

```
array[0] -> <a href=
array[1] -> www.google.com
array[2] -> >HOMEPAGE</a>
```

so we assign the `[1] index` to the data.

In the HTML then you need to use it as following:

```
<a href="{{data.desc}}">HOMEPAGE</a>
```

> There's still a problem to fix

If you click the link generated by this you will **NOT** navigate to the site you've specified on that object because you are missing the `http://` string before the site. The result, if you click the link, in the url, will be:

```
localhost:yourport/www.yoursite.ext
```

In order to fix that you can modifiy the assign (the first line of code of this answer) like that:

```
this.data.desc = 'http://' + this.data.desc.split(/\'(.*?)\'/)[1]
```

You don't need to worry about the `HTTPS` protocol because, usually, if a site work in HTTPS instead than HTTP you will be re-directed in the HTTPS protocol by the server.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume data is

```
dataJSON = {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "POC",
        "desc": "<a href='www.google.com'>HOMEPAGE</a>",
        "status": "done",
        "percentage_finished": 100
    }
```

We can get href value using DOM parser.

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(dataJSON.desc, 'text/html');
const elementA = parsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("a");
if(elementA && elementA.length > 0){
    let hrefVal = elementA[0].getAttribute("href");
    if(href.indexOf("http")===-1) hrefVal = "http://" + hrefVal;////add http if link is without it

    ////set in data if you want to use in html
    dataJSON.href = hrefVal;
}
```

In Html

```
<a [attr.href]="dataJSON.href">HOMEPAGE</a>
```

Hope it helps.